# error in pluload on check image size : parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

i use plupload for upload image, and i wnat check image width and height with this code

```
                init: {

                    FilesAdded: function (up, files) {


                        jQuery.each(files, function (i, file) {

                            var reader = new FileReader();

                            reader.onload = function (e) {
                                var img = new Image;
                                img.src = e.target.result;
                                img.onload = function () {

                                    // access image size here using this.width and this.height

                                }
                            }


                            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
                        });

                    }
                }
```

but i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

how i can fix this problem ?

thank you for your help